# Segmentation fault in PyStan

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, bayesian, pystan

I am learning pystan and I tried to run the following code, which I copy-pasted from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-introduction-to-bayesian-inference-in-pystan-c27078e58d53):

```
#/my_file.py

import pystan as ps
import numpy as np

model = """
data {
    int<lower=0> N;
    vector[N] x;
    vector[N] y;
}
parameters {
    real alpha;
    real beta;
    real<lower=0> sigma;
}
model {
    y ~ normal(alpha + beta * x, sigma);
}
"""

# Parameters to be inferred
alpha = 4.0
beta = 0.5
sigma = 1.0

np.random.seed(101)
# Generate and plot data
x = 10 * np.random.rand(100)
y = alpha + beta * x
y = np.random.normal(y, scale=sigma)

# Put our data in a dictionary
data = {'N': len(x), 'x': x, 'y': y}

# Compile the model
sm = ps.StanModel(model_code=model)
```

When I run it with `python3 my_file.py` I get

> INFO:pystan:COMPILING THE C++ CODE FOR MODEL anon_model_(long hash) NOW.
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

It has been impossible to run it in a NoteBook, it is just worst.

I have tried other tutorials with the same outcome.

I have tried to track the problem with a debugger, and the code stops in the file */pystan/model.py*, at the line 384:

```
self.module = load_module(self.module_name, lib_dir)
```

When I jump into load_module, it stops in `return __import__(module_name)`, after which I fall in a rabbit hole (I get lost), and the debugger log message is long and incomprehensible to me. For example, in one line it states: *AttributeError: partially initialized module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'rcParams' (most likely due to a circular import)*

OS: Ubuntu

I installed pystan using a YML file like:

```
name: bayesian
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.9
  - numpy
  - pystan
  - matplotlib
    ...
```

Comment: Which version of `pystan` is installed?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Michael Ruth's comment, I checked the version and it was 2.19.*, so I edited the YML like

```
name: bayesian
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.9
    ...
  - pip
  - pip:
      - pystan
```

Now I have to import stan, not pystan, and the new version is 3.7.0. I run the "eight schools" example in the [official webpage](https://pypi.org/project/pystan/) successfully.